# Pip isn't installing packages in virtual environment

Tags: python, python-venv

On windows, with python 3.9.5.

I create a virtual environment using `python -m venv env`. I activate it, no problems.
I verify that when using `pip` and `python` I use those of my virtual environment, no problems here.

I type `python -m pip install wheel`. Because I'm still using venv, pip should try to install in `.\env\Lib\site-packages`, yet pip is trying to install it in `C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\site-packages`.
I have the same results when using `pip install wheel`

Can somebody explain what is wrong and what should I do to solve this?

Commands and outputs:
`python -m venv env` --> folder created

`.\env\Scripts\activate` --> virtual environment activated

`where python` --> `C:\Users\user\Documents\env\Scripts\python.exe` and `C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe`

`pip -V` --> `pip 21.1.1 from c:\users\user\documents\env\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)`

`python -m pip install wheel` -->

> Collecting wheel
> Using cached wheel-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
> Installing collected packages: wheel
> Successfully installed wheel-0.37.0
>
> WARNING: Target directory C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\site-packages\wheel already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
> WARNING: Target directory C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\site-packages\wheel-0.37.0.dist-info already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
> WARNING: Target directory C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\site-packages\bin already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.

Comment: Please provide the exact commands you are running and their exact outputs.

Comment: 1. source venv/bin/activate 
2. (venv) <- should appear
3. (venv) pip -V.  <- should show path of venv python lib folder
4. (venv) pip install wheel

Comment: @python_user I already tried, it didn't work

Comment: @ReshamWadhwa (venv) did appear and pip -V show me the path of the venv pyhton folder

Comment: Since you say `pip -V` shows correct location, why don't you do `pip install` instead of `python -m pip install`? I have no idea why would `python -m pip` go to the wrong place but since just `pip` is *in* correct place use just `pip`.

Comment: @h4z3 because it gives the same result. I should make it clear

Comment: Try to delete the virtual environment and created a new one, the problem may be solve

Comment: @matin I already tried 5 times before, but thank you

Comment: Is it possible you've set some environment variables like `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: can you try  venv/bin/python3 -m pip install wheel ? instead of using the default python

Comment: @Iguananaut I didn't

Comment: @ReshamWadhwa it's not the default python that is used, it's the one in venv folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can force pip to install the packages where we want using the `-t` parameter

Example:

- go to `env\Lib\site-packages`
- use `pip install -t . package` or `python -m pip install -t . package`

It should work correctly after that

Comment: True but this could cause problems if not using the right pip for the right Python environment. It would be better to resolve the underlying issue which, like many questions like this, is probably hard to determine without some interactive debugging, as it's probably some combination of environment configuration issues.